# Some Problem In Using DataSet.ReadXML

Tags: c#, readxml

i want to use dataset.readxml for retrieve some data from xml file.But,my xml format is not well format,one part is for dataset and another part for other things.so,how i retrieve the dataset part.i am developing in c#.net 2008.xml file format is like below.

```
<Object type="Sample">
  <Object type="Tool">
    <Property name="Text">Prescription1</Property>
    <Property name="Name">Prescription1</Property>        
  <Object type="TextBox">    
    <Property name="Text">Singapore</Property>
    <Property name="Name">TextBox2</Property>    
  </Object>      
  <DataSet>                          //This Part
    <TableOne>      
      <ItemID>001</ItemID>
      <ItemName>Item001</ItemName>
      <Price>100</Price>      
    </TableOne>
    <TableOne>
      <ItemID>002</ItemID>
      <ItemName>Item002</ItemName>
      <Price>200</Price>      
    </TableOne>
  </DataSet>
</Object>
```

regards

Chong

Comment: Your accept rating is pretty low. I see in some other questions you have what seems like the right answers but haven't accepted them as such. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as xml is not well format it is not possible to use the DOM parser.
So you can the string manipulation

```
 string fileContent =  System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"sample.xml");
        int firstIndex =  fileContent.IndexOf("<DataSet>", 0);
        int lastIndex = fileContent.IndexOf("</DataSet>", firstIndex);
        string data = fileContent.Substring(firstIndex + "<DataSet>".Length, lastIndex - firstIndex - "<DataSet>".Length);
```

Data contents the your dataset part

Answer (score 1):

Some thing like that ? (where xmlTest is the string containing your XML)

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        // Get the Xml
        doc.LoadXml(xmlTest);
        // Get your DataSet Node
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("Object/DataSet");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        // Read your node
        ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(node.OuterXml));
        // Read your daat
        string value = ds.Tables["TableOne"].Rows[0]["ItemID"];
```

Comment: If you load not well formated xml  .. the doc.LoadXml(xmlTest); will throw exception

Comment: If you load not well formated xml, you may not have a DataSet node.
But you're right, exception have to be handle.

Comment: In the above question he has mentioned that his xml content is not well format.

Comment: What I understand, is that there are data he does not need in his DataSet. But i can be wrong.
In that case, your answer is better.

Comment: thanks Mahantesh and Kerrubin,both of your answers are very useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some thing like this:

```
XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(strfilename);
xmlreader.ReadToFollowing("sometext");
xmlreader.ReadToDescendant("textundersometext");
```